# passing SQLiteOpenHelper via Intent - android

Tags: android, service

I have a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and implements `Serializable` like this:

```
public class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements Serializable {
    public final static String DB_NAME = "testDB";
    public final static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public final static String tableName = "information";

    SQLiteDatabase mWritableDB = null;

    public dbHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.setmWritableDB(db);
     // more code
    }
...//more code
}
```

I need to pass an instance of this class to a service, and I have my `MainActivity` do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    mService service=null;
    boolean mBound = false;
    public dbHelper mdbHelperActivity = null;
    public static final String serializableExtraName = "DBHelper";

    private ServiceConnection connection = createNewServiceConnection();

    public ServiceConnection createNewServiceConnection() {
      return   new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder iService) {
                mService.LocalBinder binder = (mService.LocalBinder) iService;
                service = binder.getService();
                mBound = true;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "service has connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                mBound = false;
            }
        };
    }

    public void insertNewData(View view){
        if( mBound && (service != null ) ){
            service.insert();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mdbHelperActivity = new dbHelper(this);
    }

    public void startService(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,  mService.class );
        intent.putExtra(serializableExtraName,mdbHelperActivity);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

In the service class I have the following code to get from the `Serializable` like this(in the `onStartCommand` method:

```
public class mService extends Service implements Serializable {

    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "mForegroundService";
    private NotificationChannel serviceChannel = null;
    private int pendingIntentRequestCode = 0xFAD;
    private Looper serviceLooper = null;
    private ServiceHandler serviceHandler;
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();
    private dbHelper mdbHelperService = null;
    private boolean initializeDB = false;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
        mService getService(){
           return mService.this;
        }
    }

    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler{
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper){
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            //do some work based on message
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments");
        thread.start();
        serviceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(serviceLooper);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mdbHelperService = (dbHelper)intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.serializableExtraName);


        this.createNotificationChannel();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,pendingIntentRequestCode,notificationIntent,0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Test Service")
                .setContentText( "Test Service content here" )
                .setSmallIcon( R.drawable.ic_launcher_background )
                .setContentIntent( pendingIntent )
                .build();
        startForeground(1, notification);

        Message msg = serviceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        serviceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        if(!initializeDB){
            initializeDB = true;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "service has started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

but, then I find out that the `SQLiteOpenHelper` is not serializable, with the following exception:

```
Process: com.mexample.serviceapp, PID: 29781
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.mexample.serviceapp.mService@41efab00 with Intent { cmp=com.mexample.serviceapp/.mService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = com.mexample.serviceapp.dbHelper)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2872)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = com.mexample.serviceapp.dbHelper)
        at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2222)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2321)
        at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
        at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:1295)
        at android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.java:4838)
        at com.mexample.serviceapp.mService.onStartCommand(mService.java:72)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2855)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; IllegalAccessException
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.resolveConstructorClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:712)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:673)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1985)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
        at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2220)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2071) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2321) 
        at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249) 
        at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:1295) 
        at android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.java:4838) 
        at com.mexample.serviceapp.mService.onStartCommand(mService.java:72) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2855) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What can I do to pass the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class via the `Intent`, or any other method if possible at all?

Comment: Just use a thread safe Singleton.  https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html

Comment: @MarkKeen,  So, it was not that it was not serializable?

Comment: it is not serializable. You can't serialize the class, nor would you want to, because it would require every field in `SQLiteOpenHelper` being serialzable as well - which it is not. A Singleton is a single "instance", serializable is something completely different and more like the ability to "clone" using a bytestream (read the inrerface contract). The hashcode would be the same for a Singleton, not for 2 "cloned" serialized objecst.

Comment: @MarkKeen, then could you tell me what was the idea of using a singleton? How would I pass it to an intent without it being serializable?

Comment: @MarkKeen , and what do you mean by hasCode when you say: "The hashcode would be the same for a Singleton, not for 2 "cloned" serialized objecst"

Comment: these questions are way outside the scope of your original question I suggest some further reading on Singletons if you don't know what they are - https://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples

Comment: @MarkKeen , okay, I just came across the term Parcelable , can you just give me a hint( maybe even a yes or no) if implementing parcelable would allow me to send it in an intent?